# Feed Me Plugin: Can Match fields but feed not importing

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I can detect and match up the fields from my json file but when doing the import I get the following error in the log:

```
No feed items to process.   3/28/2019 2:53 PM

error   Unable to reach data/case-studies.json. Message: File path cannot be found.
```

For some reason, it isn't picking up the file when doing an import. How do I resolve this?

I have validated the json file and it is correct so I'm stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info may be outdated now, but just for anyone else who Googles "File path cannot be found " and ends up here (this page is the only result), it seems Feed Me is incompatible with the AsyncQueue plugin. I uninstalled Async Queue, and the import from Feed Me ran without issue.

Comment: Have you put in a support ticket on the Feed Me plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to send a support ticket through the plugin? I'm happy to help (as the developer of Feed Me), but I'd need some more information about your setup, including the current version you're on, the path you're using, etc.